# What actions/stats are affected by player height and weight?

Tags: nba2k14

When you create your player for the MyCareer mode, you can set your height and weight. What actions do these affect in game, and how much? For example, I would assume that a 6'6" player would be better at blocking than a 6'0" player, but by how much? And how would that interact with the block stat?

What are the upsides and downsides to making my player shorter or taller, or lighter or heavier?